# What is the best way to update table with related column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have no idea how to resolve my problem, so I hope you can help me with that. So, I have one table, for example TableA:

```
Id  Code    ProductId  RelatedId
1   APlus   100        NULL
2   AMinus  100        NULL
3   BPlus   200        NULL
4   BMinus  200        NULL
```

Now, I have RelatedId = NULL, and I want to take this results:

```
Id  Code    ProductId  RelatedId
1   APlus   100        2
2   AMinus  100        1
3   BPlus   200        4
4   BMinus  200        3
```

For each ProductId, and Code is strictly connected with each other (it is opposite with the same Code Plus - Minus).

Should I create some Cursor? But what should I take? Id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `outer apply`.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*, t2.id
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t
      where t2.productid = t.productid and
            t2.code <> t.code
     ) t2;
```

This assumes that there are two rows, one minus and one plus.  You can be more explicit:

```
select t.*, t2.id
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t
      where t2.productid = t.productid and
            (t2.code like '%Plus' and t.code like '%Minus') or
             t2.code like '%Minus' and t.code like '%Plus'
            )
     ) t2;
```

I should note that this easily adapts to an `update`:

```
update t
    set relatedid = t2.id
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t
      where t2.productid = t.productid and
            t2.code <> t.code
     ) t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subquery` :

```
select t.*, t2.id as RelatedId
from table t outer apply 
     ( select top 1 t1.id
       from table t1
       where t1.productid = t.productid and
             t1.code <> t.code
     ) t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
update cte set cte.RelatedId  = cte1.Id from CTE 
inner join CTE cte1 on CTE.ProdecTid = cte1.ProdecTid and CTE.Id != cte1.Id
```

here CTE is your table Name